# Select all instances of quoted text from a file

Tags: bash, unix, grep, text-manipulation

Is there any way to `grep` or obtain in any other way all instances of text within each pair of double quotes in a file? I've seen answers like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435056/grep-string-inside-double-quotes but they don't work on cases where each line may contain an arbitrary number of quoted strings.

So for an input like this:

```
Here was some "text over here", and then there was "text over there".
```

I would want the output to be:

```
"text over here"
"text over there"
```

Does not have to include the quotes themselves.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat aaaa
foo "bar" base "ere" fff
"fff"ggggg"rr"

$ grep -o '"[^"]*"' aaaa
"bar"
"ere"
"fff"
"rr"
```

Comment: This command works just fine without the `P`.

Comment: @Scott ok.. though -P is generally very useful, because without -P the regex features are a bit primitive.. For example, `echo 1111 | grep -o 1{2}`   all that asks for is for '1' to occur twice, but without the P  the {1} or {2} or {2,3} won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
grep -o '"[^"]*"' /path/to/file
```

Note: `[^"]*` is the non-greedy version of the wildcard (`.*`), so you can match more than one occurrence per line.

Comment: It will match more than one occurrence, though since you use the term "non greedy version",  i'd point out to you that the star is still greedy. If you wanted what you call non greedy.. The way you make it what you call "non greedy" i.e. lazy, would be `*?` e.g. `.*?` I doubt that `[^*]*` would be called non greedy , though perhaps it could be said to be less greedy than `".*"` (if the terminology is indeed used that way). But certainly as far as the terminology goes. * is greedy and *? is lazy.

Comment: I will selfishly prefer this because of the lack of `-P` option (not supported on some systems), though of course, `text` was just an example, but that can be fixed by just removing the damn string `text` from the command.